# Javascript not redirecting

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have searched extensively for the javascript code to redirect to a different page on the same site and in the same folder and I have tried numerous things. I'm unable to get it to work in localhost or on the web-server. This is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_submit()
{
    var con = confirm("Submit form and print invoice?");
    var url = 'dashboard.php?del=no';
    if (con == true) {
        document.location.href = url;
        /*I have also tried:
        window.location = 'dashboard.php?del=no';
        window.location.replace("dashboard.php?del=no");
        window.location.href = "dashboard.php?del=no";
        */
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the code on the button :

```
onclick="return(confirm_submit())"
```

From everything I've read this should work but it is not working. Can someone please tell me why it is not working and what I need to do to make it work? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I have answered the question below. It's a workaround, but it is doing the job.

Comment: If you submit the form, you can't also redirect, because submitting reloads the page and stops the current script.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried it without the submit as well. I will edit the question to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: You can submit via AJAX, and redirect in the success function. Or have dashboard.php send a redirect header.

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript console for errors?

Comment: check this `preventDefault()`, http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Does adding `return false` after the `document.location.href` assignment fix it?

Comment: @Barmar no, it made no difference.

Comment: Are you using JQuery? If yes, why not use a handler for submit or click event using preventDefault method instead of return false?

Comment: @giubueno Could you provide me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this will work without submitting your form

```
var url = window.location.href;
splitUrl = url.split("/");
splitUrl[splitUrl.length-1]="your page";
url = splitUrl.join("/");
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: @Barmar hmm!sorry for that. now I have edited my answer

Comment: it's working on my localhost. What error or warning its showing @Spud

Answer (score 0):

I have spent too much time on this issue so I have decided to go a different route. I'm using javascript to change the value of a hidden field and then using PHP to redirect to the other page as a result of the posted value of the hidden field. Thanks to all who have given their time to this matter on my behalf. Cheers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_submit()
{
    var con = confirm("Submit form and print invoice?");
    if (con == true) {
        document.getElementById('bool').value = true;
        $("#edit_workorder").submit();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And the PHP is:

```
if($bool == true) {
    header("Location:dashboard.php?del=no");
    exit;
}
```

It's doesn't really answer the question, but it works and that is more important to me right now.